# Where can i find the 404 template from OpenLiteSpeed?

Tags: linux, http-status-code-404, html

I want to change/customize the standard **404** (Not Found) page/template  from **OpenLiteSpeed**. 
But where can i find the 404 file via terminal?

I'm searching in: `cd /usr/local/lsws/`
But can't find it.

Can someone help me please?

I'm using **AlmaLinux 8** with **OpenLiteSpeed** and **PHP 7.4**

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Open `openlitespeed.conf` and add this:

```
errorpage 404 {
  url                     /404.html
}
```

When done, restart the OpenLiteSpeed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @dawid But i think you don’t understand me.

I want to edit the standard 404 page from OpenLiteSpeed it self and not add my own custom 404.html.

So where can i find the standard 404 template from OpenLiteSpeed? This template: https://prnt.sc/3rpbLBEIB2-w

Comment: do you understand me?